# How to mitigate floating point error in recursive DSP calculations

Tags: python, math, floating-point, signal-processing, numerical-methods

I have implemented a modified linear prediction coding function like this:

```py
def modified_lpc_process(s: NDArray, p: int, fs: int) -> NDArray:
    a = lpc_coefficients(s, p)
    a_hat = modified_pole_coeffs(a, fs=fs)
    # a_hat = a # debug line
    s_hat = numpy.zeros(len(s))

    for n, sn in enumerate(s):
        as_accum = 0
        for k in range(len(a)):
            if n - 1 - k < 0:
                break
            as_accum += a[k] * s[n - 1 - k]
        un = sn + as_accum

        as_hat_accum = 0
        for k in range(len(a_hat)):
            if n - 1 - k < 0:
                break
            as_hat_accum += a_hat[k] * s_hat[n - 1 - k]

        s_hat[n] = -as_hat_accum + un
        round(s_hat[n], 8)

    return s_hat
```

Which essentially implements the maths here:
[image]

I have noticed that the floating point error in this operation quickly blows up and I end up with sample values too large. In an effort to debug, I've set the modified pole coefficients `a_hat` to be the same with `a`, expecting to get the same value for `s_hat` and `s`; but the same issue is still there. I've also just realised that in floating point, adding a number and subtracting the same number you end up with slightly different results, which in recursive applications like this can accumulate to large differences.

I wonder what the best practice is in this case to mitigate this error accumulation?

Comment: Some filters are inherently unstable, regardless of floating-point rounding errors. Have you determined whether the coefficients for your filter produce a stable filter or not? You have not shown the coefficients, so nobody else can examine them and the resulting behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I imagine that OP means `(x+y)-y != x` (in some cases), which is important to remember when working with finite precision numbers

Comment: The python code looks too complicated compared to the screenshot formula. How about just `u = [s[n]+sum(a[k]*s[n-1-k] for k in range(len(a))) for n in range(len(s))]`

Comment: Interesting question, but since this is primarily conceptual, it's off topic here; try dsp.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Oh, it seems like you are trying to use numpy. Then it can be even more concise using [numpy.convolve](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)